# Wrong structure of calling global variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, coding-style

My structure code is wrong i guess.Because the tkmassagebox info always shows C.It supposedly when the total = 3 then the tkmassagebox shows A. Although the total get 3 correct the result still remain the same which C.Can someone fix my problem.Below is my code you guys can try it on your own.

```
import Tkinter 
import tkMessageBox

#easybox1
EasyBox1 = Tkinter.Tk()
EasyBox1.geometry("250x200")
EasyBox1.title("Quesion 1")

Tkinter.Label (EasyBox1, text="answer:").pack()

answr1 = Tkinter.Entry (EasyBox1)
answr1.pack()

LabelName2 = Tkinter.Label (EasyBox1, text="State the number of edges in a cube")
LabelName2.grid(row=1,column=0)
LabelName2.pack()

total=0
def next1():
    global total
    if not answr1.get():
        tkMessageBox.showerror('no answer')
    elif answr1.get() == 8 :
        total=total+1
        EasyBox1.withdraw()
        EasyBox2.deiconify()
    else:
        total=total
        EasyBox1.withdraw()
        EasyBox2.deiconify()
    return

#easybox2
EasyBox2 = Tkinter.Tk()
EasyBox2.geometry("250x200")
EasyBox2.title("Quesion 2")

Tkinter.Label (EasyBox2, text="answer:").pack()

answr2 = Tkinter.Entry (EasyBox2)
answr2.pack()

LabelName2 = Tkinter.Label (EasyBox2, text="What is the place value of the digit 4 in 76421?")
LabelName2.grid(row=1,column=0)
LabelName2.pack()

LabelName2 = Tkinter.Label (EasyBox2, text="A.Thousands B.Hundreds C.Ones D.Tens")
LabelName2.grid(row=1,column=0)
LabelName2.pack()

def next2():
    global total
    if not answr2.get():
        tkMessageBox.showerror('no answer')
    elif answr2.get() in ["B", "b"]:
        total=total+1
        EasyBox2.withdraw()
        EasyBox3.deiconify()
    else:
        total=total
        EasyBox2.withdraw()
        EasyBox3.deiconify()


EasyBox2.withdraw()


#easybox3
EasyBox3 = Tkinter.Tk()
EasyBox3.geometry("250x200")
EasyBox3.title("Quesion 2")

Tkinter.Label (EasyBox3, text="answer:").pack()

answr3 = Tkinter.Entry (EasyBox3)
answr3.pack()

LabelName2 = Tkinter.Label (EasyBox3, text="1234+143x23=?")
LabelName2.grid(row=1,column=0)
LabelName2.pack()

def next3():
    global total
    if not answr3.get():
        tkMessageBox.showerror('no answer')
    elif answr3.get == 4523:
        total=total+1
        EasyBox3.withdraw()
        ResultBox.deiconify()
    else:
        total=total
        EasyBox3.withdraw()
        ResultBox.deiconify()

EasyBox3.withdraw()



ResultBox = Tkinter.Tk()
ResultBox.geometry("320x260")
ResultBox.title("Results")

LabelName5 = Tkinter.Label(ResultBox, text = "Mark"+`total`+'\n')
LabelName5.pack

def mark():
    global total_mark
    total_mark = total
    if total_mark == 3:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo('A')
    elif total_mark == 2:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo('B')
    else:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo('C')
ResultBox.withdraw()

Tkinter.Button (EasyBox1, text="Next", command=next1).pack()
Tkinter.Button (EasyBox2, text="Next", command=next2).pack()
Tkinter.Button (EasyBox3, text="Next", command=next3).pack()
Tkinter.Button (ResultBox, text="Result", command=mark).pack()


EasyBox1.mainloop()
```

Comment: @WoLy please help me for the last time

Comment: You should not create more than a single root window. Tkinter is designed to always have exactly one instance of `Tk`. If you need additional windows you should create instances of `Toplevel`.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple bugs that keep the user from getting a perfect score.  Bug #1 is in next1(): you compare the answer to 8 but it's coming back as a string so you should be comparing it to '8' or calling int() on it:

```
def next1():
    global total
    if not answr1.get():
        tkMessageBox.showerror('no answer')
    elif answr1.get() == '8':
        total = total + 1
    EasyBox1.withdraw()
    EasyBox2.deiconify()
```

Bug #2 is in next3() where you make the same error as next1() above but also compound it by comparing to answr3.get instead of answr3.get()

```
def next3():
    global total
    if not answr3.get():
        tkMessageBox.showerror('no answer')
    elif answr3.get() == '4523':
        total = total + 1
    EasyBox3.withdraw()
    ResultBox.deiconify()
```

Fixing those, your user, and you, will be on track for a perfect score.

Comment: there still bug in it. If there is no answer then we click button next.Then the tkmassagebox will pop up .If we close it the next interface continue thats the problem

Comment: @student, I suggest you close off this question and post a new one with the specific code with which you're having problems and what you desire it do that it isn't doing. You can include a link back to this question for additional background on your problem.